# LayoutManager for RecyclerView Grid with different cell width

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

`StaggeredGridLayoutManager` doesn't seem to allow customising a **cell width** or span multiple columns (except full span) for vertical orientation.

[image]

What is a preferred `LayoutManager` for organising cells as shown above?

**P.S.** I just want to know how to customise **cell width** and not height with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. I know height can be customised as implemented in this [sample](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/adapters/SimpleStaggeredAdapter.java).

```
public class VerticalStaggeredGridFragment extends RecyclerFragment {

    public static VerticalStaggeredGridFragment newInstance() {
        VerticalStaggeredGridFragment fragment = new VerticalStaggeredGridFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager getLayoutManager() {
        return new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected RecyclerView.ItemDecoration getItemDecoration() {
        return new InsetDecoration(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    protected int getDefaultItemCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter getAdapter() {
        return new SimpleStaggeredAdapter();
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class SimpleStaggeredAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VerticalItemHolder itemHolder, int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(itemHolder, position);

        final View itemView = itemHolder.itemView;
        if (position % 4 == 0) {
            int height = itemView.getContext().getResources()
                    .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_staggered_height);
            itemView.setMinimumHeight(height);
        } else {
            itemView.setMinimumHeight(0);
        }
    }
}
```

`itemView.setMinimumWidth(customWidth)` doesn't affect cell width.

To simplify, I update my grid layout to

[image]

How to increase cell 0 width as compared to cell 1 in a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` or any other layout manager?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams` to change width and height of cells, What you expect to design follows a simple pattern, If you assign every cell an index (in the order that `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` arranges them by default) you will have this:

```
index % 4 == 3           --->  full span cell
index % 8 == 0, 5        --->  half span cell
index % 8 == 1, 2, 4, 6  ---> quarter span cell
```

first declare some constants in adapter to define span types:

```
private static final int TYPE_FULL = 0;
private static final int TYPE_HALF = 1;
private static final int TYPE_QUARTER = 2;
```

Then override `getItemViewType` method in your adapter like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    final int modeEight = position % 8;
    switch (modeEight) {
        case 0:
        case 5:
            return TYPE_HALF;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 4:
        case 6:
            return TYPE_QUARTER;
    }
    return TYPE_FULL;
}
```

All you need to do is change layoutparams considering `viewType` of the `holder`:

```
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final View itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
    itemView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            final int type = viewType;
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = itemView.getLayoutParams();
            if (lp instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams sglp =
                        (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_FULL:
                        sglp.setFullSpan(true);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_HALF:
                        sglp.setFullSpan(false);
                        sglp.width = itemView.getWidth() / 2;
                        break;
                    case TYPE_QUARTER:
                        sglp.setFullSpan(false);
                        sglp.width = itemView.getWidth() / 2;
                        sglp.height = itemView.getHeight() / 2;
                        break;
                }
                itemView.setLayoutParams(sglp);
                final StaggeredGridLayoutManager lm =
                        (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) ((RecyclerView) parent).getLayoutManager();
                lm.invalidateSpanAssignments();
            }
            itemView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    });

    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(itemView);
    return holder;
}
```

My adapter always returns 50 for items count(just a test) and I used a simple layout file for items, It contains a `LinearLayout` and a `TextView` to show the position of holder, Remember you should pass 2 for `spanCount` (int the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` constructor) because of your design.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager lm =
            new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
    rv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

}
```

[image]

**PS**:
For lazy people like me maybe it's a simpler way rather than extending my custom `LayoutManager`, But I'm sure there are better ways to achieve this.

**Update**:
Updated part of your question is more simpler, You can use `GridLayoutManager`:

```
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (position % 3 == 2) {
                return 3;
            }
            switch (position % 4) {
                case 1:
                case 3:
                    return 1;
                case 0:
                case 2:
                    return 2;
                default:
                    //never gonna happen
                    return  -1 ;
            }
        }
    });
    rv.setLayoutManager(glm);
```

In this way you set 3 for default span size, Then considering the position of your span, Each item occupies 1, 2 or 3 spans, Something like this:

[image]

```
Item0.width == 2 X Item1.width
Item2.width == 3 X Item1.width
Item0.width == 2/3 X Item1.width
```

Comment: Are you able to set cell width to 1/4 or 3/4 or say specific size in dp for a grid with span size 2? I was able to set custom height but not width with staggeredgridlayoutmanager. You'll notice cells in my image are not of equal width in the 1st row. I will try your solution too in some time and get back.

Comment: That's exactly what I did if you check onCreateViewHolder method.

Comment: Can you update code in your answer for the grid image i provided? I wont be able to try your solution until tomorrow.

Comment: NaN I tried your solution. Unfortunately I cannot change cell width in the first row with the approach. I updated my question to simplify layout. Thanks a lot for your interest. +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The last part about gridlayout solved my problem :)

Comment: It was super great help. Shout out to open communities :D

Comment: can I have `getSpanSize` inside `onBindViewHolder` so I know which item from my data should have different span size?

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda `GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup` is an abstract class and YOU are telling it what it should return, So you undoubtedly know the pattern, In case that you insist on using `getSpanSize` method, just pass an instance to the adapter!

Comment: @FarshadTahmasbi Can you have a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607773/how-to-make-a-collection-of-images-with-in-a-view-in-android-studio-using-recycl?noredirect=1#comment114332130_64607773

Comment: that was help me alot

Answer (score 8):

For everyone else, looking for a solution without simplifying your layout, you can have a look to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275082/recyclerview-layoutmanager-for-changing-row-and-column-span/43502224#43502224), or you can read more.

Big thanks to [Nick Butcher](https://github.com/nickbutcher)! His layout manager called `SpannableGridLayoutManager` is capable of doing this.

1. Download SpannableGridLayoutManager [from here](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/6a3cb17ede0ffeffb4ca16e4fd3c2ab60900d6b8/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/recyclerview/SpannedGridLayoutManager.java)

   For some reason I had to change this line:

   ```
   while (availableSpace > 0 && lastVisiblePosition < lastItemPosition) {
   ```

   to

   ```
   while (lastVisiblePosition < lastItemPosition) {
   ```

   to got the manager working.
2. Set SpannableGridLayoutManger to your RecyclerView

In your case:

```
SpannedGridLayoutManager manager = new SpannedGridLayoutManager(
            new SpannedGridLayoutManager.GridSpanLookup() {
                @Override
                public SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo getSpanInfo(int position) {
                    switch (position % 8) {
                        case 0:
                        case 5:
                            return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(2, 2);

                        case 3:
                        case 7:
                            return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(3, 2);

                        default:
                            return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(1, 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            3, // number of columns
            1f // default size of item
    );
```

Which will give you exactly what is in the first picture of the question.

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the file you mentioned, included it in my project, made the change you mentioned but when scroll through items, the app crashes with this:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getTop()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @blueware Where Can you tell me where? Which file on what line?

Comment: file: `SpannableGridLayoutManger`, no exact line. If you want I can attach my stacktrace for that exception.

Comment: @blueware you can put your stacktrace to Pastebin and share the url

Comment: @kristyna ... recyclerView takes lots of space from top please help me out

Comment: @VishalYadav I would have to see your code. Any padding you forgot to delete in the code or xml? Maybe the image on its own has some blank space?

Comment: @VishalYadav i have same isue, recyclerView takes lots of space from top, you are already fix it ? please help me too

Comment: @kristyna you found the problem about this issue ? "recyclerView takes lots of space from top"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351715/recyclerview-takes-lots-of-space-from-top-after-use-spannedgridlayoutmanager

Answer (score 7):

Finally did it, it will help everyone who is trying to achieve any kind of patterns

I was looking for the same result but with one **header** and lazy loading **footer**.
I tried **@Kristyna** answers of  [Nick Butcher Library](https://github.com/android/plaid/blob/6a3cb17ede0ffeffb4ca16e4fd3c2ab60900d6b8/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/recyclerview/SpannedGridLayoutManager.java) too. But it has many issues like *fast scrolling view disappear problem* with the [extra space or fixed cell height](https://github.com/android/plaid/issues/830) *issue*.

I found another library of Arasthel [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager) and tried to implement it. But it also has many issues like *fixed height* and *footers extra space* issue

Finally, after 5hr of digging Arasthel's SpannedGridLayoutManager, I fixed the issues and found my result.

My final edited forked library **download** from here [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/noowenz/SpannedGridLayoutManager).

[image]
[image]

**In my case**

```
  val adapter = GridItemAdapter()//This is your adapter
  val spannedGridLayoutManager = SpannedGridLayoutManager(orientation = VERTICAL, spans = 3)
  spannedGridLayoutManager.itemOrderIsStable = true
  recyclerview.layoutManager = spannedGridLayoutManager
```

For the **first** image result

```
  spannedGridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup { position ->
        when {
            position == 0 -> {
                /**
                 * 150f is now static 
                 * should calculate programmatically in runtime
                 * for to manage header hight for different resolution devices
                 */
                SpanSize(3, 1, 150f)
            }
            position % 7 == 1 ->
                SpanSize(2, 2)
            else ->
                SpanSize(1, 1)
        }
    }
  recyclerview.adapter = adapter
```

And the **second** image result

```
 spannedGridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup { position ->
        when (position % 8) {
            0, 5 ->
                SpanSize(2, 2)
            3, 7 ->
                SpanSize(3, 2)
            else ->
                SpanSize(1, 1)
        }
    }
    recyclerview.adapter = adapter
```

This **spanSizeLookup** logic may vary according to the requirement, for me I had set it randomly for testing purposes.

Comment: Just wanted to talk you. This lib is amazing and exactly what I needed. I spend some days before finding something like this.

Comment: Thanks @Tgo1014. If you want to talk to me, please send me an email.

Comment: ops, I meant thank you instead of talk you. And thanks too for making yourself available for talking on email :)