# RecyclerView layoutmanager for changing row and column span

Tags: android, android-layout, grid, android-recyclerview, html-table

I am looking to create the following layout (red sqaures does not really have to be squares, a custom fixed height is also fine). The layout seems very simple yet I did not find a layout manager which suits my needs.

[image: wat i want]

I tried the StaggeredGridLayoutManager but this only allows to set the span of either the column or the row, not both.

Is there floating around a custom layout manager which is able to do this?
I have looked at TwoWayView but changing height seems to be problematic and the library is not being maintained.

Anyone having this problem and solved it?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514887/layoutmanager-for-recyclerview-grid-with-different-cell-width/36518658#36518658

Comment: @Brianvdb have you solve this if yes can you help me to get out from this.It will be great help thanks...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A little bit late, but it might help everyone else...

I was looking for the same and finally, after 2 days of googling I found a solution. Big thanks to [Nick Butcher](https://github.com/nickbutcher)! His layout manager called `SpannableGridLayoutManager` is capable of doing this. In my case I was doing a pattern like your first two rows:

[image]

Solution is easy:

**1. Download SpannableGridLayoutManager [from here](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/6a3cb17ede0ffeffb4ca16e4fd3c2ab60900d6b8/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/recyclerview/SpannedGridLayoutManager.java)**

For some reason I had to change this line:

```
while (availableSpace > 0 && lastVisiblePosition < lastItemPosition) {
```

to

```
while (lastVisiblePosition < lastItemPosition) {
```

to got the manager working.

**2. Set SpannableGridLayoutManger to your RecyclerView**

In my case:

```
    SpannedGridLayoutManager manager = new SpannedGridLayoutManager(
            new SpannedGridLayoutManager.GridSpanLookup() {
                @Override
                public SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo getSpanInfo(int position) {
                    // Conditions for 2x2 items 
                    if (position % 6 == 0 || position % 6 == 4) {
                        return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(2, 2);
                    } else {
                        return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(1, 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            3, // number of columns
            1f // how big is default item
    );
```

Which gave me exactly what I wanted (numbers are position of item in adapter):

[image]

**EDIT: error with styleable**
Put those lines into `attrs.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="SpannedGridLayoutManager">
    <attr name="android:orientation" />
    <attr name="spanCount" />
    <attr name="aspectRatio" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: I am trying your answer however, there is an error on line 54 `TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.SpannedGridLayoutManager, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);` - `//R.styleable.SpannedGridLayoutManager` is not found

Comment: @SNos see the edit. You have to declare a style for your manager

Comment: @kristyna when I add 7 images in recyclerview and after scroll then 6 number position image display only half and when I add 1 more image in a list then scroll it's working well. How it solve?can you help me?

Comment: @kristyna do you have example for this please help

Comment: @MaheshVayak I would have to see the code. Do you have some margins or paddings in the layout which can cause seeing just a half?

Comment: @kristyna thanks for help , I have solved  and got the expected result

Comment: @kristyna, there is a problem with this `LayoutManager` as when there is one item, its not showing, any help?

Comment: Mine code is working fine even for one item. Sorry I cant help. The only workaround can be setting different LayoutManger in case you have only one item.

Comment: @kristyna, would you mind sharing your final `SpannedGridLayoutManager` code with us?

Comment: @kristyna would you mind helping me out? https://i.imgur.com/6HlqwFn.jpg here is the screenshot. I am not able to scroll, so that I can see the rest of the big image. If I remove the smaller one, then scroll works correctly. I use version published in github. For SpanInfo I just return 2x2 if position % 6 == 0.

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue for our particular case. problem lied in scrollVerticallyBy(), else clause. LayoutManager would take the last item. If item previous to last had span bigger than the last one, i.e., 2x2 vs 1x1, then list would not scroll, because the "bottom" value was from the smaller item. I have hardcoded, that if previous item was the big one, then take the "bottom" value from that one. However this is not a general solution. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: @kristyna How to get first and last visible item position?

Comment: thanks fow verry helpful answer, please tell me, // Conditions for 2x2 items 
                    if (position % 6 == 0 || position % 6 == 4) , whats must i do if i want to show for 3x3 items. thanks

Comment: after follow your answer, i got some issue, please check my question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57351715/recyclerview-takes-lots-of-space-from-top-after-use-spannedgridlayoutmanager

Comment: @Yudikarma I dont have the project to try it, but if you want 3x3 (and 3 small items items on the side) then it would be (position % 8 == 0 || position % 8 == 5) return new SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanInfo(3, 3);
And also if I am not wrong you have to change the column number to 4.

Comment: You are a life saver ! How did find this !??

Comment: Please find the latest SpannedGridLayoutManager in `grid_span` branch, which fixed many issues I met by the version of the original post.
[link](https://github.com/android/plaid/blob/grid_span/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/recyclerview/SpannedGridLayoutManager.java)

Comment: Hello All! Thanks for this! Awesome. I only have a small issue. I do not want to have nested scrolling inside my recycler view. I changed the canScrollVertically to false but then not all items are showing in the main Scrollview.
Do you have any idea how to fix?

Comment: @MehdiSatei you don't want the recycler view to scroll? Maybe it doesn't show because there is not enough space for all the items? I can only guess here. I have never tried that.

Comment: @kristyna I don't want a nested scroll inside the recycler view. What I have in my activity is a ScrollView with multiple recycelerviews. What I would like to have is a simple scrolling behaviour as a flat page. But what I have is a scrolling recycerview inside a scrollview (nested scrolling). If I turn off the nested scrolling, it will disappear completley

Comment: Can anyone tell me? Can I set different 'cellAspectRatio' for each cell of the item?

Comment: I have some issues while integrating this library. How to remove extra space of item https://github.com/android/plaid/issues/830

Comment: There is little issue in the code. When there is only 1 item, it is not visible at all. Can someone suggest me solution.

Answer (score 6):

Finally did it, it will help everyone who is trying to achieve any kind of patterns

I was looking for the same result but with one **header** and lazy loading **footer**.
I tried **@Kristyna** answers of  [Nick Butcher Library](https://github.com/android/plaid/blob/6a3cb17ede0ffeffb4ca16e4fd3c2ab60900d6b8/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/recyclerview/SpannedGridLayoutManager.java) too. But it has many issues like *fast scrolling view disappear problem* with the [extra space or fixed cell height](https://github.com/android/plaid/issues/830) *issue*.

I found another library of Arasthel [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager) and tried to implement it. But it also has many issues like *fixed height* and *footers extra space* issue

Finally, after 5hr of digging Arasthel's SpannedGridLayoutManager, I fixed the issues and found my result.

My final edited forked library **download** from here [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/noowenz/SpannedGridLayoutManager).

[image]

**In my case**

```
  val adapter = GridItemAdapter()//This is your adapter
  val spannedGridLayoutManager = SpannedGridLayoutManager(orientation = VERTICAL, spans = 3)
  spannedGridLayoutManager.itemOrderIsStable = true
  recyclerview.layoutManager = spannedGridLayoutManager
```

And

```
  spannedGridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup { position ->
        when {
            position == 0 -> {
                /**
                 * 150f is now static 
                 * should calculate programmatically in runtime
                 * for to manage header hight for different resolution devices
                 */
                SpanSize(3, 1, 150f)
            }
            position % 7 == 1 ->
                SpanSize(2, 2)
            else ->
                SpanSize(1, 1)
        }
    }
  recyclerview.adapter = adapter
```

This **spanSizeLookup** logic may vary according to the requirement, for me I had set it randomly for testing purposes.

Comment: @WebDiva you can use this class anywhere if your projects are in JAVA.

Comment: It throws 'java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
        at com.arasthel.spannedgridlayoutmanager.SpannedGridLayoutManager.fillAfter(SpannedGridLayoutManager.kt:623)

Comment: @WebDiva Which branch are you using? Try custom-layoutparams branch

Comment: @WebDiva sorry  there is no custom-layoutparams, use dev or dynamic_layout.

Comment: Sorry I was using the default implementation. I have changed it to yours now. Let's if it works now.

Comment: The issue persists. I think this is the issue. I have an adapter of empty arraylist. The arraylist is filled after after a network call. Maybe because the size of the items in the arraylist are 0 before the network call, it could crash. But this is not the case with LinearLayoutManger, GridLayoutManager or StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Comment: @WebDiva which branch are you using?

Comment: I am using your branch.

Comment: @WebDiva I have more than 3 branch, can you name it?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. I followed your link and got the spannedgridlayoutmanager code right away.

Comment: Okay so I was using your dev branch. This line of code ```val lastAddedRow = (layoutEnd - extraHeight) / rectsHelper.itemSize``` in the fillAfter() method is the culprit.

Comment: This is because you haven't provided height of recycler view in case of orientation horizontal and width in case of vertical

Comment: This seems to cut off parts of the last elements in certain cases, when the last items are all bigger than 1x1. Any idea why this could happen? I'm using the dev branch

Comment: Please try other branches as per required like: dynamic_layout, fix-empty-space-at-bottom or get_2×2_layout_position.