# How to create a layout like instagram explore with flexboxlayoutmaanger in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to create a recyclerview that shows images like instagram tab. I have checked this [Implement Asymmetrical Grid Layout Manager Like Instagram Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56680985/implement-asymmetrical-grid-layout-manager-like-instagram-search) question but it does not seem to do the work. I tried using gridlayoutmanager but I can't make it work. How to recreate it with google's FlexboxLayoutManager or a custom layout manager? Hope you'll answer. Regards.

Comment: check this lib https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Comment: here is another https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/pinterest-masonry-layout-staggered-grid/

Comment: Thank you. I will check it up and let you know if it worked

Comment: I can't find how to implement it using the first library and I think it's not possible with the second library.

Comment: @WebDiva second answer from Priyanka helped me to create this back in March of 2020. So it worked for me!

Comment: Can you please help me with it? The bounty expires in 9 hours and I don't want it go to waste. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/android/plaid/blob/6a3cb17ede0ffeffb4ca16e4fd3c2ab60900d6b8/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/recyclerview/SpannedGridLayoutManager.java) from Nick Butcher as layout manager for your `RecyclerView`.

Here how it looks like in action, i used it for creating the sample layout below.

[image]

Comment: Yes I used it but there are so many errors in it. For example, when there is only one item, it would not show up. And when I call notifydatasetchanged after clearing and adding new items, it throws arrayoutofbounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me so well [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://gist.github.com/Ric17101/5df2a88ec54bc5be734bdeb47aeada82).

[image]

```
  // Sample usage from your Activity/Fragment
  private fun setupSpannedGridLayout() {
        val manager = SpannedGridLayoutManager(
            object : GridSpanLookup {
                override fun getSpanInfo(position: Int): SpanInfo {
                    // Conditions for 2x2 items
                    return if (position % 6 == 0 || position % 6 == 4) {
                        SpanInfo(2, 2)
                    } else {
                        SpanInfo(1, 1)
                    }
                }
            },
            3,  // number of columns
            1f // how big is default item
        )
        recyclerView.layoutManager = manager
        adapter = GridAdapter(arrayListOf())
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
```

PS: i am using kotlin here :).

Comment: Yes I have tried this one as mentioned in the above answer. Try setting the number of items in the recyclerview to 1 or reloading the recyclerview with notifydatasetchanged. It does not show up in the former case and crashes in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above answer use [SpannedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager).
To show grids similar to instagram use below code

```
var spannedGridLayoutManager = SpannedGridLayoutManager(
        orientation = SpannedGridLayoutManager.Orientation.VERTICAL,
        spans = 3
    )
spannedGridLayoutManager.itemOrderIsStable = true
spannedGridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup =
        SpannedGridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup { position ->

            var x = 0
            if (position % 9 == 0) {
                x = position / 9
            }
            when {
                position == 1 || x % 2 == 1 || (position - 1) % 18 == 0 ->
                    SpanSize(2, 2)
                else ->
                    SpanSize(1, 1)
            }

        }
    recyclerView.layoutManager = spannedGridLayoutManager
    recyclerview.adapter = searchGridAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

for the newest Instagram layout in 2022 you can try this:

```kotlin
layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = IGLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup { position ->

            // 0  1  2
            // s  s  b
            // 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
            // s  s  s  s  s  s  s  s  b
            // 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112
            // s   s   s   s   s   s   s   s   s   s   s   s   b
            // 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121
            // s   s   s   s   s   s   s   s   b

            if (position < 2) {
//                ILog.debug("???", "$position is small")
                bigItemFlag = 0
                SpanSize(1, 1)
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
//                ILog.debug("???", "$position is big")
                bigItemFlag = 11
                SpanSize(1, 2)
            }
            else if (position % 11 == 0 && position == bigItemFlag) {
                bigItemFlag += 13
//                ILog.debug("???", "$position is big, $position mod 11 is ${position % 11}")
                SpanSize(1, 2)
            }
            else if (position % 11 == 2 && position == bigItemFlag) {
                bigItemFlag += 9
//                ILog.debug("???", "$position is big, $position mod 11 is ${position % 11}")
                SpanSize(1, 2)
            }
            else {
//                ILog.debug("???", "$position is small")
                SpanSize(1, 1)
            }
        }
```