# Android RecyclerView Make fixed grid layout with combined rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to make a layout like this:

[image]

I tried with this code, but the second and third item's height are same as the first item.

```kotlin
val lm = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
lm.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == 0) 2
        else 1
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43502224/8956604

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir: thanks, this worked as well