# Dynamic grid cell size in RecyclerView - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using `RecyclerView` to display data using `GridLayoutManager` , but I could only generate it with fixed columns. How do I dynamically display something like this image
[image]

Comment: You can use StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Comment: You can create recyclerView with multiple custom cellViews, I guess in your case you will have two different cells. Or, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514887/layoutmanager-for-recyclerview-grid-with-different-cell-width

Comment: Swayangjit & Walid your suggestions helped, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

Try like this

```
yourRecylerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

For details [see this article.](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)